# Solving recurrent equations with RSolve

Tags: difference-equations

I need to find (or guess?) the symbolic functional form of aFun[n] for a general n (where n>=1). Anyone can help?

```
aFun[n_] :=
 Block[
  {a},
  a[-1, 0] = 0;
  a[n + 1, 0] = 0;
  a[-1, 1] = 0;
  a[n + 1, 1] = 0;
  With[{eqs = 
     Table[{a[i, 0] == 
         i /n ( v + 
             b (alpha a[i, 0] + (1 - alpha) a[i - 1, 0])) + (1 -
              i /n) (v - p + 
             b (alpha a[i + 1, 1] + (1 - alpha) a[i, 1])), 
        a[i, 1] == 
         i /n ( v + 
             b (alpha a[i, 0] + (1 - alpha) a[i - 1, 0])) + (1 -
              i /n) (v - p (1 - w) + 
             b (alpha a[i + 1, 1] + (1 - alpha) a[i, 1]))}, {i, 
        0, n}, {x, 0, 1}] // Flatten, 
    vars = Table[a[i, x], {i, 0, n}, {x, 0, 1}] // Flatten}, 
   a[0, 0] /. First@Solve[eqs, vars]]
  ]
```

Comment: Recurrence is of order 2, so you need one more initial condition.

Comment: I don't think that's the issue; adding one doesn't produce a result, and mathematica usually includes undetermined constants if the solution is underdetermined anyway, so that shouldn't be an issue. It might simply be not solvable by mathematica...

Comment: The start condition you specify is simply the recursion, therefore you can not determine `a[0]` from this information. More info is needed. The start condition must be independent from the recursion.

Comment: Thanks for the comments. I do not have any other conditions to add. Say m = 4, we will have 5 equations in this series with five unknowns: a[0], a[1], a[2], a[3], a[4]. Why we would need any additional info?

Comment: I believe you only have 4 equations in the original, relating the following sets of variables: `a[0], a[1]`; `a[0], a[1], a[2]`; `a[1], a[2], a[3]`; `a[2], a[3], a[4]`. The example seems to include `a3` twice in the final equation.

Comment: Sorry, that was a typo, I fixed it.

Comment: What is the purpose of the `{x, 0, 1}`? It just seems to produce duplicates in the `eqs` and `vars` lists.

Comment: Let's say n=3, then we have 8 equations and 8 variables. We have 2*(n+1) distinct equations and 2*(n+1) distinct variables.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'm not totally sure `RSolve` is the best way to approach this; I'm also not sure the below is the best way to approach it either! But I was able to get it to work:

```
a0[m_] := Block[{a},
  a[-1] = 0; a[m + 1] = 0; 
  With[{eqs = Table[a[n] == n/m (v + b a[n - 1]) + (1 - n/m) (v - p + b a[n + 1]), {n, 0, m}],
        vars = Table[a[n], {n, 0, m}]}, 
       a[0] /. First @ Solve[eqs, vars]]]
```

Comment: This was super helpful. Thanks alot

Comment: Curiously, a general solution for `a[0]` in terms of `m` seems to be `a[0] -> ((-m + (m - 1) b) p + (m - (m - 2) b) v)/(m - 2 (m - 1) b + (m - 2) b^2)`